# Theory Behind Euler's Phi Function's Implemention

Tags: math, theory

I have found a implemention of euler's phi function on topcoder. The code is given below:

```
int fi(int n) {          
    int result = n;          
    for(int i=2;i*i <= n;i++) {            
        if (n % i == 0) result -= result / i;            
           while (n % i == 0) n /= i;          
    }          
    if (n > 1) result -= result / n;          
    return result;        
}
```

I want to know the exact theory behind this implemention. What I am understanding is if I get a integer that divides n, then I am subtracting `result/i` from result(I don't know why).Then the code divides n by i until it is divisible. What I didn't understand is last part of the code.

```
if(n > 1) result -= result / n;
```

What I know is if n is greater than 1 at this stage, then n will be a prime number. I want to know, if what I am understanding from this code so far is correct and the exact theory behind this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up **Euler's totient function**.

If a number `n` is decomposed into a product of power of primes, then

```
phi(p1^m1*...*pk^mk) = (p1-1)*p1^(m1-1)*...*(pk-1)*pk^(mk-1)
```

which the algorithm faithfully computes.

It is the number of remainder classes mod `n` that are invertible. It is the exponent for the extended little theorem of Fermat, if `gcd(a,n)=1` then

```
a ^ b == a ^ (b mod phi(n))  mod n
```

---

The iteration finds the prime factors of the input `n` in ascending order. If `p` is found as prime factor, then `result = k*p^m` where `m` is also the multiplicity of `p` in the input. The operation `result -= result/p` has the result

```
result = k*p^m - k*p^(m-1) = k*(p-1)*p^(m-1).
```

And you are right, `n>1` after the iteration will happen when the largest prime factor has multiplicity `m=1`, and in the totient value this factor occurs reduced by `1`.